# Count min,max of each feature of a dataset and store in other data frame using Panda

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data_frame "x" with few features. I want to count the min, max, datatype etc of each feature and store to my new DF. Below is my code snippet:

`import panda as pd`
`import numpy as n`

`stats = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Type", "Min", "Max", "Mean", "Std"])`

`for col in x.columns:`
    `stats.loc[col] = {"Type": x[col].dtypes,` 
                       `"Min": x[col].min(),`
                       `"Max": x[col].max(),`
                      `}`

Getting error: cannot set a row with mismatched columns
Let me know of any suggestions

Comment: Can you include your dataframe in your post? Or at least a small sample of your dataframe, showing your different features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to have a quick look at your dataframe, call x.[describe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html)(), this will give you the mean, std, min and max among others.

If you actually want to store this data for each column, you can build it like this:

```
stats = pd.DataFrame()
stats.insert(0, 'Type', x.dtypes)
stats.insert(0, 'Min', x.min())
stats.insert(0, 'Max', x.max())
etc...
```

Comment: This works. Can you please explain me the working of it? Also, I know about describe() but did not want to use it,

Comment: df.min() gives a dataframe of one column with the minimum values of each column of df. The rows are labeled with the column name. This dataframe column is then inserted as a new column at column position 0 with name 'Min'. Does this help?

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you